# How to convert flat xml data to hierarchical data xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have to convert a flat xml to hierarchical xml.
I have no idea for this task. 
Below is input for conversion.

Input:-

```
<body>
    <p class="title">Article Title</p>
    <p class="Authors">abc, pqr and xyz</p>
    <p class="intro">here is introdution text......</p>        
    <p class="head1">1: Heading level 1</p>
    <p>some text here</p>
    <p>some text here</p>
    <p class="head2">1.1: Heading  level 2</p>
    <p>some text here</p>
    <p>some text here</p>        
    <p class="head3">1.1.1: Heading  level 3</p>
    <p>some text here</p>
    <p>some text here</p>        
    <p class="head1">2: Heading level 1</p>
    <p class="head2">2.1: Heading  level 2</p>
    <p>some text here</p>
    <p>some text here</p>        
    <p class="head3">2.1.1: Heading  level 3</p>
    <p>some text here</p>
    <p>some text here</p>        
    <p class="head3">2.1.2: Heading  level 3</p>
    <p>some text here</p>
    <p>some text here</p>        
</body>
```

I want to convert it to below given xml.

Output:-

```
<article>
    <title>Article Title</title>
    <Authors>abc, pqr and xyz</Authors>
    <introduction>here is introdution text......</introduction>
    <body>
        <sec level="1">
            <title>1: Heading level 1</title>
            <p>some text here</p>
            <p>some text here</p>
            <sec level="2">
                <title>1.1: Heading  level 2</title>
                <p>some text here</p>
                <p>some text here</p>
                <sec level="3">
                    <title>1.1.1: Heading  level 3</title>
                    <p>some text here</p>
                    <p>some text here</p>                    
                </sec>
            </sec>
        </sec>
        <sec level="1">
            <title>2: Heading level 1</title>
            <sec level="2">                
                <title>2.1: Heading  level 2</title>
                <p>some text here</p>
                <p>some text here</p>
                <sec level="3">
                    <title>2.1.1: Heading  level 3</title>
                    <p>some text here</p>
                    <p>some text here</p>                        
                </sec>
                <sec level="3">
                    <title>2.1.2: Heading  level 3</title>
                    <p>some text here</p>
                    <p>some text here</p>                        
                </sec>
            </sec>                
        </sec>
    </body>
</article>
```

I havn't any idea to convert it using xslt.

I am getting below Output:-

```
   <article>
  <p class="title">Article Title</p>
  <p class="Authors">abc, pqr and xyz</p>
  <p class="intro">here is introdution text......</p>
  <body>
     <p class="head1">1: Heading level 1</p>
     <p>some text here</p>
     <p>some text here</p>
     <p class="head2">1.1: Heading level 2</p>
     <p>some text here</p>
     <p>some text here</p>
     <p class="head3">1.1.1: Heading level 3</p>
     <p>some text here</p>
     <p>some text here</p>
     <p class="head1">2: Heading level 1</p>
     <p class="head2">2.1: Heading level 2</p>
     <p>some text here</p>
     <p>some text here</p>
     <p class="head3">2.1.1: Heading level 3</p>
     <p>some text here</p>
     <p>some text here</p>
     <p class="head3">2.1.2: Heading level 3</p>
     <p>some text here</p>
     <p>some text here</p>
  </body>
  </article>
```

My code is :-

```
      <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
     <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="html">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="head"/>
     <xsl:template match="body">
        <xsl:element name="article">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="p[@class='title']|p[@class='Authors']|p[@class='intro']"/>
           <xsl:element name="body">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="p[preceding-sibling::p[@class='intro']]"/>
           </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
     </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Do you think it would be of high educational value to provide someone with an answer who "hasn't any idea" how to do it? Try to solve your problem - or at least google the title of your question.

Comment: @LuvKS Please refrain from personal remarks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175991/xslt-turn-flat-list-into-hierarchy/9176808#9176808 for an XSLT 2.0 solution for a similar problem, basically you need to write a recursive function or template using `for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="p[@class = concat('head', $level)]"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below xslt code for expected output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf" version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element(section)*">
    <xsl:param name="entries" as="element(p)*"/>
    <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$entries"
        group-starting-with="p[@class = concat('head',$level)]">
        <xsl:variable name="P_ID" select="generate-id(.)"/>
        <section name="{@class}">
            <title>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </title>
            <xsl:if test="following-sibling::p[1][not(@class)]">
                <ps>
                    <xsl:apply-templates
                        select="following-sibling::p[not(@class)][generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[@class][1]) = $P_ID]"
                    />
                </ps>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group() except ., ($level + 1))"/>
        </section>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(p[contains(@class,'head')], 1)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that uses a recursive function to achieve the nesting and of course some further templates to transform the various `p` elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="mf:group" as="element()*">
    <xsl:param name="elements" as="element(p)*"/>
    <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$elements" group-starting-with="p[@class = concat('head', $level)]">
       <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="not(self::p[@class = concat('head', $level)])">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <sec level="{$level}">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                  <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group() except ., ($level + 1))"/>
                </sec>
              </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="body">
  <article>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="p[@class = 'head1'][1]/preceding-sibling::*"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(p[@class = 'head1'][1]/(., following-sibling::*), 1)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </article>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[@class = 'title'] | p[starts-with(@class, 'head')]">
  <title>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </title>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[@class = 'intro']">
  <introduction>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </introduction>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[@class = 'Authors']">
  <Authors>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Authors>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1.0:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="html">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="head"/>

<xsl:key name="Body" match="p[not(@class)]"
    use="generate-id((preceding-sibling::p[@class='Head1'] | preceding-sibling::p[@class='Head2']| preceding-sibling::p[@class='Head3']| preceding-sibling::p[@class='Head4']| preceding-sibling::p[@class='Head5']| preceding-sibling::p[@class='Head6'])[last()])"/>
<xsl:key name="h2" match="p[@class='Head2']"
    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[@class='Head1'][1])"/>
<xsl:key name="h3" match="p[@class='Head3']"
    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[@class='Head2'][1])"/>
<xsl:key name="h4" match="p[@class='Head4']"
    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[@class='Head3'][1])"/>
<xsl:key name="h5" match="p[@class='Head5']"
    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[@class='Head4'][1])"/>
<xsl:key name="h6" match="p[@class='Head6']"
    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[@class='Head5'][1])"/>

<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:element name="article">
        <xsl:apply-templates
            select="p[@class='title']|p[@class='Title']|p[@class='Authors']|p[@class='intro']"/>
        <xsl:element name="body">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('Body',generate-id())" mode="Body"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::p[@class='Head1']" mode="h1"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p" mode="h1">
    <sec level="1">
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </title>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('Body',generate-id())" mode="Body"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('h2',generate-id())" mode="h2"/>
    </sec>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p" mode="h2">
    <sec level="2">
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </title>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('Body',generate-id())" mode="Body"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('h3',generate-id())" mode="h3"/>
    </sec>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p" mode="h3">
    <sec level="3">
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </title>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('Body',generate-id())" mode="Body"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('h4',generate-id())" mode="h4"/>
    </sec>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p" mode="h4">
    <sec level="4">
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </title>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('Body',generate-id())" mode="Body"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('h5',generate-id())" mode="h5"/>
    </sec>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p" mode="h5">
    <sec level="5">
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </title>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('Body',generate-id())" mode="Body"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('h6',generate-id())" mode="h6"/>
    </sec>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p" mode="h6">
    <sec level="6">
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </title>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('Body',generate-id())" mode="Body"/>
    </sec>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p" mode="Body">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>            
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```